# How to convert CSV decimals into C float values

Tags: arrays, c, csv, multidimensional-array, file-read

I need to convert a CSV file of decimal numbers into a C float variable. How can I do that?

data.csv

```
0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5
1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5
2.1,2.2,2.3,2.4,2.5
3.1,3.2,3.3,3.3,3.5
4.1,4.2,4.3,4.4,4.5
```

output:

```
------------START OF PROGRAM------------
Filesize: 99 Bytes

CSV_content =
[ 0.100000 0.200000 0.300000 0.400000 0.500000 ]
[ 1.100000 1.200000 1.300000 1.400000 1.500000 ]
[ 2.100000 2.200000 2.300000 2.400000 2.500000 ]
[ 3.100000 3.200000 3.300000 3.300000 3.500000 ]
[ 4.100000 4.200000 4.300000 4.400000 4.500000 ]

------------END OF PROGRAM------------
```

Comment: So, what do you actually want here? A 2D array of floats or that neatly formatted output?

Comment: gre_gor: This is a self answered post. I got sidtracked in a project and ended up creating a CSV file reader for float matrixes, that places the information into a variable of type float *. After loading into a variable, A printMatrix function is called using said variable as an argument. Thay gives the nice output.

Answer (score 0):

This is my self Answer. My old answer post was deleted. So if you see comments about correcting things that have already been corrected (in here or my quesrion post), that's why.

Latest version of the Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

const int MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINE = 128;
const int MAX_LINE_SIZE = 256;
const int MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING_ELEMENT = 11; // for floats. Increase for double 0.1234567\0 = 10 character.
const char NULL_TERMINATOR = '\0';
const char NEW_LINE_CHARARACTER = '\n';

typedef struct
{
    int numberOfString; // number of string
    char **data;        // stringArray->data[i] is a string.
} StringArray;

typedef struct
{
    char ***data;
    int numberOfStringArray;
    int numberOfString; // number of string
} StringMatrix;

char *readCSV_toString(char *filename, int printFileBool, unsigned long *fileSize_output)
{

    FILE *filePointer = fopen(filename, "rb");
    if (filePointer == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s","Can't open file '");
        fprintf(stderr,"%s",filename);
        fprintf(stderr,"%s","'\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    fseek(filePointer, 0L, SEEK_END);
    unsigned long fileSize = ftell(filePointer); // get length of file
    rewind(filePointer);                         // return to beginning of file

    char *fileContent = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (fileSize) + 1);
    if (fileContent == NULL)
    {   
        fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate memory for file %s\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    fread(fileContent, sizeof(char), fileSize / sizeof(char), filePointer);
    fileContent[fileSize] = NULL_TERMINATOR; // add nullterminator

    if (printFileBool == 1)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < fileSize + 1; i++)
        {
            printf("%i ", fileContent[i]);
        }
    }

    fclose(filePointer);
    *fileSize_output = fileSize;
    return fileContent;
}

int substringCompare(char *stringInput, int start_index, int end_index_excluded, char *stringToBeCompared)
{
    char *stringInputCut = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * (end_index_excluded - start_index) + 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < end_index_excluded - start_index; i++)
    {
        stringInputCut[i] = stringInput[i + start_index];
    }
    // printf("max i (included):%d \n",end_index_excluded - 1);
    stringInputCut[end_index_excluded - start_index] = NULL_TERMINATOR;
    // printf("substring cut: '%s'\n", stringInputCut);
    int return_value = strcmp(stringInputCut, stringToBeCompared);
    free(stringInputCut);
    return return_value;
}

int string_splitLength(char *string, unsigned long stringSize, char *delimiter)
// return the number of element in arrayList that the initial string will be split into
{
    int length = 0;
    int delimiterLength = strlen(delimiter);
    // printf("string size :%d\n",stringSize);
    for (unsigned long i = 0; i < stringSize - delimiterLength + 1; i++)
    {
        if (substringCompare(string, i, i + delimiterLength, delimiter) == 0 && (string[i + delimiterLength] != NULL_TERMINATOR))
        {
            // printf("___The substring is: %c%c___\n", string[i], string[i + 1]);
            length++;
        }
    }

    return length + 1; // because there (a,b,c,d): 3 commas, 4 number. Hence +1
}

StringArray *string_split(char *string, char *delimiter, int maxElementSize)
// return the string.split(delimiter)
{
    StringArray *stringArray = calloc(1, sizeof(StringArray)); // the big thing
    stringArray->numberOfString = string_splitLength(string, maxElementSize, delimiter);

    int i = 0;
    char *token = strtok(string, delimiter);

    char *stringOutput_i = (char *)malloc(maxElementSize); // malloc str[i] : Important
    strncpy(stringOutput_i, token, maxElementSize);

    stringArray->data = calloc(stringArray->numberOfString, sizeof(char *)); // The array of pointers. (inside of the big thing. )
    stringArray->data[i] = stringOutput_i;
    i++;

    while (token != NULL && i < MAX_NUMBER_OF_LINE)
    {
        token = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
        if (token == NULL)
            break; // needed because it loop 1 too many time.

        char *stringOutput_i = (char *)malloc(maxElementSize); // malloc str[i] : Important
        strncpy(stringOutput_i, token, maxElementSize);

        stringArray->data[i] = stringOutput_i; // pointer copy.
        i++;
    }

    return stringArray;
}

void printStringArray(StringArray *stringArray)
{
    int n = stringArray->numberOfString;
    printf("The string array with length %d is: \n", n);
    printf("[ ");

    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray->numberOfString; i++)
    {
        printf("'%s'", stringArray->data[i]);
        if (i < n - 1)
            printf(",");
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("]\n");
}

StringMatrix *getStringMatrix(StringArray *stringArray_input, char *delimiterElement, int maxElementSize)
{
    StringMatrix *stringMatrix = calloc(1, sizeof(StringMatrix));
    stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray = stringArray_input->numberOfString;

    char buffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    strncpy(buffer, stringArray_input->data[0], MAX_LINE_SIZE);
    StringArray *initArray = string_split(buffer, delimiterElement, MAX_LINE_SIZE);

    stringMatrix->numberOfString = initArray->numberOfString;

    stringMatrix->data = malloc(stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray * sizeof(char **));
    for (int i = 0; i < stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray; i++)
    {
        stringMatrix->data[i] = malloc(stringMatrix->numberOfString * sizeof(char *));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray; i++)
    {
        StringArray *elementArray = string_split(stringArray_input->data[i], delimiterElement, MAX_LINE_SIZE);
        for (int j = 0; j < stringMatrix->numberOfString; j++)
        {

            stringMatrix->data[i][j] = (elementArray->data[j]); // pointer copy
        }
    }
    return stringMatrix;
}

void printStringMatrix(StringMatrix *stringMatrix)
{
    int m = stringMatrix->numberOfString;
    int n = stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray;
    printf("The string matrix is: %d %d\n", m, n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("[ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("'%s' ", stringMatrix->data[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

float *stringToFloat_matrix(StringMatrix *stringMatrix, int *m_output, int *n_output)
{

    int n = stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray; // vertical (list of list)
    int m = stringMatrix->numberOfString;      // horizontal (last layer)

    float *array1D = calloc(m * n, sizeof(float));

    float(*matrix)[m] = (float(*)[m])array1D;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {

            matrix[i][j] = (float)atof(stringMatrix->data[i][j]);
        }
    }

    *m_output = m;
    *n_output = n;
    return array1D;
}

void freeStringArray(StringArray *stringArray)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringArray->numberOfString; i++)
    {
        free(stringArray->data[i]);
    }
    free(stringArray->data); // stringArray (-> numberOfString  , -> data -> [ p0, p1, p2, p3,... ] -> { string1, string2, string3,... } )
    free(stringArray);
}

void freeStringMatrix(StringMatrix *stringMatrix)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < stringMatrix->numberOfStringArray; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < stringMatrix->numberOfString; j++)
        {
            free(stringMatrix->data[i][j]);
        }
        free(stringMatrix->data[i]);
    }
    free(stringMatrix->data);
    free(stringMatrix);
}

float *openCSV_float(char *filename, char *delimiterLine, char *delimiterElement, int printFileContentBool, int *m_output, int *n_output)
{
    unsigned long fileSize;
    char *fileContent = readCSV_toString(filename, printFileContentBool, &fileSize);
    if (fileContent == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Filesize: %lu Bytes\n\n", fileSize);

    StringArray *stringArray = string_split(fileContent, delimiterLine, MAX_LINE_SIZE);
    printStringArray(stringArray);
    printf("-------\n");

    StringMatrix *stringMatrix = getStringMatrix(stringArray, delimiterElement, MAX_LENGTH_OF_STRING_ELEMENT);
    printStringMatrix(stringMatrix);

    int m, n;
    float *array1D = stringToFloat_matrix(stringMatrix, &m, &n);
    *m_output = m;
    *n_output = n;
    // Could have put m_output, n_output in stringToFloat_matrix. And would save on 3 line of code and a bit more performance
    // But decided to be verbose.
    free(fileContent);
    freeStringArray(stringArray);
    freeStringMatrix(stringMatrix);

    // other stuff to free? idk. Should be the main leak solved.
    return array1D;
}

void printMatrix_float(float *array1D, int m, int n)
{
    float(*matrix)[m] = (float(*)[m])array1D;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        printf("[ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            printf("%f ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("]\n");
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("\n\n------------START OF PROGRAM------------\n");

    int n, m;
    int printFileContentBool = 0;
    float *array1D;

    char delimiterLine[2] = {NEW_LINE_CHARARACTER, NULL_TERMINATOR};
    char delimiterElement[] = "||";
    char filename[100] = "data2.csv";

    array1D = openCSV_float(filename, delimiterLine, delimiterElement, printFileContentBool, &m, &n);
    // 1kb of memory leak per file opening loop;

    printf("CSV_content =\n");
    printMatrix_float(array1D, m, n);

    printf("\n------------END OF PROGRAM------------");
    return 0;
}
```

Data.csv

```
0.1||0.2||0.3||0.4||0.5
1.1||1.2||1.3||1.4||1.5
2.1||2.2||2.3||2.4||2.5
3.1||3.2||3.3||3.3||3.5
```

Output

```
------------START OF PROGRAM------------
Filesize: 95 Bytes

The string array with length 4 is:
[ '0.1||0.2||0.3||0.4||0.5', '1.1||1.2||1.3||1.4||1.5', '2.1||2.2||2.3||2.4||2.5', '3.1||3.2||3.3||3.3||3.5' ]
-------
The string matrix is: 5 4
[ '0.1' '0.2' '0.3' '0.4' '0.5' ]
[ '1.1' '1.2' '1.3' '1.4' '1.5' ]
[ '2.1' '2.2' '2.3' '2.4' '2.5' ]
[ '3.1' '3.2' '3.3' '3.3' '3.5' ]

CSV_content =
[ 0.100000 0.200000 0.300000 0.400000 0.500000 ]
[ 1.100000 1.200000 1.300000 1.400000 1.500000 ]
[ 2.100000 2.200000 2.300000 2.400000 2.500000 ]
[ 3.100000 3.200000 3.300000 3.300000 3.500000 ]

------------END OF PROGRAM------------
```

Comment: The structure are needed because It's for me, the simplest method to access and read info.

Some better programmer would use different struct with less heap allocation for faster performance through caching or no struct at all. Though that might cause readability problem.

I like to do 
stringArray = file.open.read().split("\n");
stringMatrix = StringArray.split(",");
for csv. I dislike using fgets to read line by line. I'd rather open the whole file in memory. 

My preference might not be the best though. What are your thoughts.

Comment: Slurping the whole file works while the file is not too big (for an ill-defined value of "too big").  It probably uses more memory than necessary, though.  I'm not clear why line-by-line processing using `fgets()` or POSIX `getline()` is not more sensible.  You can also consider memory-mapping the file if you're on a system that supports the operations.

Comment: The new `data.csv` file uses a double pipe separator, which is a little unusual.  Using three calls to `fprintf()` in `fprintf(stderr, "%s","Can't open file '"); fprintf(stderr,"%s",filename); fprintf(stderr,"%s","'\n");` is odd; why not `fprintf(stderr, "Can't open file '%s'\n", filename);`?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler And `ftell()` only returns a `long`, which is only 32 bits on Windows.

Comment: || is to show that it can now use string delimiter, rather then char delimiter.     I tried to use one fprint and it didn't work. So I used many.    I'm working on other project now

Comment: Compiling with warnings enabled spots this problem: `fprintf(stderr, "Can't allocate memory for file %s\n");`

Comment: Those are two good points Jonathan. 1) . Personnal preference. Didn't go for the best implementation, just what seemed easier. If It can't hold a big fileContent in the heap, it can't hold float * matrix in the heap, which is a min 1/3, max 2* of it's size.  Close enough for a physicist to be 1. ------ 2) I tried printf syntax but it bugged. Didn't want to spend lots of type figuring it out for what is basically a quick change due to an answer while I'm swamp with work, on what id a side tracked project. (It's the end of the semester). So I used the surrest way of using single line fprintf.